# AWS Security Group Error

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group

On Amazon Web Services, I'm connecting an Elastic Beanstalk environment to an RDS database, per [the tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console#rds-external-defaultvpc). Launching the database instance worked fine; I connected it to a security group.

[image]

Adding the security group to my environment then fails. If I try to add the group name `rds-launch-wizard`, I get an error - use group id. If I try to add the group id `sg-10bea66b`, I get the error `Security Group does not exist`.

[image]

The security group does exist. What's going on?

Comment: Can you also include the screenshot of the security groups in your account and also why are you adding it twice?

Comment: The second entry is my local IP, so I can access it through psql. I'll add the security groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RDS instance is inside a VPC, whereas your Elastic Beanstalk application is in EC2-Classic (outside any VPC).

With some exceptions, only security groups that are in the same VPC can be added to each other.

Resolution: Put your EB application in the same VPC as your RDS instance.

Comment: Thanks. How do I add the EB application to the VPC?

Comment: That is another question you need to post :)

Comment: Short answer: during the new eb application wizard, you're given the option to put the app in a vpc. Say yes at that time.